# Google Chrome changes GET method to OPTIONS using javascript fetch

Tags: javascript, authorization, token, fetch

```
fetch(BaseURL + type, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer' + token
    }

}
```

When I use `GET` method it changes the method to `OPTIONS`. Works fine with Safari. Sometimes when I refresh the page, it shows GET method but most of the time it shows `OPTIONS 200ok` status and returns no data.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to make cross origin requests. Due to CORS, it first send options(preflight) request to check if cross origin requests allowed on server, if it returns 200 ok, then it should send next get request as well.
http://restlet.com/company/blog/2016/09/27/how-to-fix-cors-problems/